# Cucumber complains that one of my steps is undefined, but not the others

Tags: java, cucumber, frameworkium

All of my other steps work. The one giving me trouble is:

```java
@Then("the response from the service at '{string}' has the keys")
public void the_response_from_the_service_at_has_the_keys(final String base_key, final String snippet) {
    ...code...
}
```

And in my feature file:

```
And the response from the service at 'output.records[0].data' has the keys
"""
["stack", "server", "apple"]
"""
```

I'm using a library called [Frameworkium](https://frameworkium.github.io/), and I have no issues with any other step, and I also have a step with the `{string}` expression which is recognised.

I'm not sure what I could be doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've spoken to someone else who uses Frameworkium, and they have told me that I need to not put single quotes around the step, but still use double quotes for the features.

```java
@Then("the response from the service at {string} has the keys")
public void the_response_from_the_service_at_has_the_keys(final String base_key, final String snippet) {
    ...code...
}
```

And in my feature file:

```
And the response from the service at "output.records[0].data" has the keys
"""
["stack", "server", "apple"]
"""
```